# Get the Friends list using specific application in Facebook Using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to find my friends list using Graph API who are using the particular application like wordpress in Facebook.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to see if someone is using a different application.  You can do this test for YOUR application that the user is currently using, but in the same way that you can not see the users who "liked" a specific page (unless you are the administrator), you can not determine if a user is using an arbitrary application.

Comment: Is it possible to identify using the application id?

Comment: As I said in my answer - you can only do this if it is YOUR application - not if it is someone else's.  For example, you can not see if your friend uses the 9gag application - only the administrators of the 9gag application can see that data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help is there any way to overcome this limitation using fql other than graph api...

Comment: I'm afraid not - this is an issue of privacy.  The limitation is there to protect the users.  The graph API and fql will behave in the same way...

Comment: Thanks, So then i want something like i need to filter my friends list who are using the application that is used by me

Comment: Here is a post dealing with finding friends also using the same application - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752119/facebook-graph-api-friends-using-application

Comment: Thanks Lix :) Is there any way to achieve the same using Graph API instead of FQL

Comment: I do not think so.... But you can simply execute an FQL query through the graph API...  What SDK are you using?

Comment: iOS SDK, I am currently developing the iPhone application to give the statistics like 50% percent of your friends are using the app X. You can also try something like that

Comment: Hmm... I don't have any experience using that SDK - but I'm certain that you'll be able to find how to execute an FQL query with that SDK here on [so]...

Comment: Thanks Lix :) I try to find in that way

Comment: Construct the FQL Query in iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022522/facebook-fql-multiquery-in-ios-sdk

Adding this link for reference to others :)