# How can I know how many friends of are using an application

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-friends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Graph API - Friends using application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752119/facebook-graph-api-friends-using-application)

I'm new programming on Facebook SDK and I've some questions...

I developed an application where a user can login through facebook (it's tested and working nice) and I can show basic information like name, profile picture, etc with no problem. But I want to show him/her how many of his/her friends are also using the application.

Could anybody help me on that please... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help:

```
// Auto friends from config.
            $sAutoFriendList = getParam('facebook_connect_autofriend_list');
            if ($sAutoFriendList != '') {
                $aAutoFriendList = explode(",",$sAutoFriendList);
                foreach($aAutoFriendList as $iAutoFriend) {
                    if($iAutoFriend > 0) {
                        $this -> _oDb -> addFriend($iProfileId, $iAutoFriend);
                    }
                }
            }
            //Auto-friend members if they are already friends on Facebook
            if (getParam('dbcs_facebook_connect_facebook_friends')) {
                $this -> setFacebookFriends($iProfileId);
```

this is the code used in my site so you will need to alter the variables.